# Once you're on fire, how do you put yourself out?

Tags: enter-the-gungeon

I got set on fire by one of the enemies in Chamber 2 when I had 1.5 hearts.

I proceeded to burn to death from it.

How do you put yourself out if you get lit on fire?

Comment: Not having played the game, I'd suggest rolling.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer First thing I tried, didn't work.

Comment: Nevermind me then, it was worth a shot.

Comment: Maybe you have to stop, drop, and roll instead of just rolling :P

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you are on fire, an indicator will appear on your screen. If you roll once, the indicator will go lower, but it will not go away. If you roll 3 or 4 times as fast as you can, you should put yourself out.

If you start rolling before the indicator reaches the top, you will take no damage.

Answer (score 5):

There are water barrels randomly scattered throughout the map. Smash one open.

Careful, though, as there usually aren't many per map.